# Serialize with persistence javafx when program is terminated

Tags: java, listview, object, serialization, javafx

I am having trouble serializing an object when the program is terminated. I am basically creating an app which switches to lets say from scene1 to scene2

scene2 displays the data into a ListView.

When I run the program initially, i go from scene1 to scene2 which has the listview, lets say i add some stuff to the listview, and I return to scene 1, and then return back to scene2 which has the listview, the data is persistent with serialization when i save it into lets say 'file.txt'.

However, when i close any of the two scene windows, i tried saving the objects data into the same file, and when i re-run the application the file is empty or for some reason

Please any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for serialization:

```
 public static void writeApp(DataList dl) throws IOException{
        //@SuppressWarnings("resource")
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(dl);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
  }



public static DataList readApp()  throws IOException, classNotFoundException {
     // @SuppressWarnings("resource")
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(storeFile);
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
      DataList dl = (DataList)ois.readObject();
      //ois.close();
      return dl;
 }
```

And this is the code i used to save data when the scene is closed(terminated): (cDL is declared globally as DataList cDL = new DataList)

And i tried this for both scenes

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
          public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
                try {
                    cDL = AdminController.dl;
                    DataList.writeApp(cDL);
                    Platform.exit();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

              System.out.println("Controller is closing");
          }
      });
}
```

When the program is running and i add stuff to scene2's listview and switch to scene1 and return to scene2, the serialization works, but when i terminate the program from either of the two scenes, and then re-run the program and try to reload the object from the same file, the file seems empty for some reason.

If any more code is needed please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Point 1: when you write, you are using inline string as filepath, but when reading, you used a supposedly final String which we don't even know what it is from your code snippet. Point 2: When you say "seems empty", did you physically check the file to see if it contains anything?

Comment: Thank you soo much for commenting. The file does not seem empty, it has something in there, I dont think i am accessing it properly The file for FileInputStream is: public static final String storeFile = "file.txt";  
When I physically open the file, it has symbols inside of it.